# PHP Youtube API v3 - Direct Upload - Unauthorized message

Tags: php, youtube, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to direct upload videos to Youtube with API v3.

I'm using **service account** scenario (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=es&csw=1#scenarios), and I solved some problems in the google-api-php-client library (to read the p12 file and to avoid the isAccessTokenExpired always return false).

```
<?php
/** Config */ 
$private_key_password = 'notasecret';
$private_key_file = 'xxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12';
$applicationName = 'xxxxx-youtube';
$client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
$client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_mail = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$public_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

/** Constants */ 
$scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube';
$url_youtube_token = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

/** Create and sign JWT */ 
$jwt = new Google_AssertionCredentials($service_mail, $scope, $private_key_file, $private_key_password, $url_youtube_token);
$jwt_assertion = $jwt->generateAssertion();

/** Use JWT to request token */
$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
    'assertion' => $jwt_assertion,
);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url_youtube_token, false, $context);
```

At that point I've got the access token in a json response like this:

```
{
  "access_token" : "1/8xbJqaOZXSUZbHLl5EOtu1pxz3fmmetKx9W8CV4t79M",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

without the "created", "refresh_token" and "id_token" fields. So I fixed the *setAccessToken* Method in **Google_OAuth2** class seting the "created" field to time() if it's not set. Otherwise *isAccessTokenExpired* always return false.

Now, let's go to upload the file.

```
    try{
        // Client init 
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId($client_id);
        $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
        $client->setApplicationName($applicationName);

        $client->setAccessToken($result);

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

            if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                // @TODO Log error 
                echo 'Access Token Expired!!<br/>'; // Debug
            }

            $youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

            $videoPath = "./test.mp4";

            // Create a snipet with title, description, tags and category id
            $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
            $snippet->setTitle("fmgonzalez test " . time());
            $snippet->setDescription("fmgonzalez test " . time() );
            $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

            // Numeric video category. See
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

            // Create a video status with privacy status. Options are "public", "private" and "unlisted".
            $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
            $status->privacyStatus = "public";

            // Create a YouTube video with snippet and status
            $video = new Google_Video();
            $video->setSnippet($snippet);
            $video->setStatus($status);

            // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
            // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            // Create a MediaFileUpload with resumable uploads
            $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/*', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

            // Create a video insert request
            $insertResponse = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
                array('mediaUpload' => $media));

            $uploadStatus = false;

            // Read file and upload chunk by chunk
            $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
            $cont = 1;
            while (!$uploadStatus && !feof($handle)) {
                $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                $uploadStatus = $media->nextChunk($insertResponse, $chunk);
                echo 'Chunk ' . $cont . ' uploaded <br/>';
                $cont++;
            }

            fclose($handle);

            echo '<br/>OK<br/>';

        }else{
            // @TODO Log error 
            echo 'Problems creating the client';
        }

    } catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
        print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage(). " <br>";
        print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

But I receive an **"Failed to start the resumable upload"** message.

Debugging, the method *getResumeUri* in **Google_MediaFileUpload** I've got this response body:

```
"error": {
    "errors": [
    {
        "domain": "youtube.header",
        "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
        "message": "Unauthorized",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
    }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I've found examples about other scenarios but not about this one.

What should I do to finally upload the video file? Any example about this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I independently got to exactly where you are, having to add in the same token fields to avoid the instant token expiration, and have the same exact problem (unauthorised) with the actual upload. Did you manage to solve this problem in the end? If so how?

Answer (score 4):

It may looks trivial but did you created at least one channel in the account you want to upload the video to. I used almost the same workaround as you for the acceess_token then encountered the same problem until I went in my Youtube account upload section and saw the message create at least one channel before uploading videos. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The error response you're getting is by design. Google does not allow Youtube API access via service accounts.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service-accounts-do-not-work-with-the-youtube-api

> **Service accounts do not work for YouTube Data API calls** because
>   service accounts require an associated YouTube channel, and you cannot
>   associate new or existing channels with service accounts. *If you use a
>   service account to call the YouTube Data API, the API server returns
>   an error with the error type set to **unauthorized** and the reason set to
>   **youtubeSignupRequired**.*